# multi-tenancy asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, multi-tenant

I need to develop a multi-tenant website like

sample1.mysite.com
sample2.mysite.com

Hold on! No, this is a different problem from what you are thinking; and before giving me link to another question, please read through.

The only difference in this kind of multi-tenancy is that the target site will remain the same. Only the content/data will be filtered depending on the host site. I do have a partition key for each of these tenant sites.

www.mysite.com >> all data, specific content files (like css, images)
sample1.mysite.com >> data specific to sample1, different content files

Need to know best practices regarding this.

Comment: What's the question/Where's the problem?

Comment: you mean you want to get content based on url? if so i can suggest an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just recently I found this article : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetmvcsubdomains

This solves the problem so far, I have tested it (also, tested the cache per domain) and it seems to work just perfect.